# When you post a link on facebook how do they determine what to show in the summary?

Tags: facebook

just curious when you post a link to facebook they seem to parse out some images and some text regarding that link. Does anyone have a guess as to how they determine what text and images to show?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It uses the head title for the title, meta description for description, and pulls any images (excluding background images) that are no more than 3:1 in proportion, allowing the poster to choose.  Developers of the page in question can specify a single image to use on a per-page basis by using a  tag as such:

```
<link rel="image_src" href="/your/image/file" />
```

(If this image declaration is used, it overrides the selection of other images on the page)

Also, with the recent adoption of the [Open Graph Protocol](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph), developers can now define the title, description, and associated image a different way:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Page Title" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Page Description" />
<meta property="og:image" content="/path/to/image" />
```

Personally, I've found the latter to be helpful in case you want search engines to use one page title (the head title) and Facebook to use a different one (Open Graph title).

Answer (score 3):

If the page, you are posting a link to, has a *description* meta tag, they use that for the text.

As to the image, there's a little widget, that appears right after you paste a link and lets you choose the image to appear - among the images on the page.